# Can we fulfill the world electricity production by nuclear power?

Tags: electricity, nuclear, nuclear-power

Nuclear energy is a form of energy released from the nucleus, the core of atoms, made up of protons and neutrons. In today's world has 450 commercial nuclear power reactors operable in 30 countries.

Globally, **around 10% of our electricity** comes from nuclear. Then, can we fulfill the other 90% by nuclear power?

**Note:** *The World has an Energy problem today and approximants 100 million people lack access to sufficient Energy. Such as the next 47 Years finish the Oil in the World. However, day to day increase power/electricity usage. Then we can use 100% nuclear power to make electricity, It's cheap, Carbon-free Energy that helped to reduce global warming and etc.*

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As the name of the community suggests, we deal with fictional worlds and their rules. At the moment you are giving exactly 0 information about your world, and it looks more like you are trying to start a debate on nuclear power. Please give a good read to our [help] to understand our scope, then edit the question to fit our standards

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. Use comments to ask for clarification and address improvements to the question. Frame challenge or answer should be posted as such.

Comment: Hi and welcome, like @L.Dutch says we need to know more about your world, (although I'm not going to assume your intentions) we do need more information about what makes your world different to ours? Are you asking about an [tag:alternate-history], or what needs to happen in the [tag:near-future], or even the [tag:far-future]? If you give enough details of how you expect the world to get to 100% nuclear energy, you could even consider this to be a [tag:reality-check]. Regardless, I recommend browsing questions in those tags, taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: At the risk of of sounding like I'm providing an answer in comments (hi Dutch) if you have or build enough of the power stations then very obviously the answer would be yes (until their fuel runs out at least) which can only mean that's not the question you're really asking, which means the question lacks clarity (or that you're seeking general discussion without a specific problem to solve which can be close grounds so I'll pass on that possibility) // please add details to better define your question.

Comment: I asked this because the world has an Energy problem: https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20170313-the-biggest-energy-challenges-facing-humanity

Comment: Then you are asking in the wrong community, I am afraid.

Comment: Hello Sameera. Please forgive us, but [worldbuilding.se] easily becomes the world's dumping ground for questions that really should be answered elsewhere. This Stack's purpose is to help you develop and consistently use the rules and systems of a fictional world of your own creation. We only allow Real World questions when they specifically pertain to that previous statement. Real World questions for the sake of the Real World are off-topic here, no matter how important or urgent they may be.

Comment: The biggest problems with nuclear are accidents and waste. For your world to get all its energy from nuclear, it would need to solve those two problems. In our world, nuclear is cheap ONLY because the costs of accidents and waste is put onto the national governments. We humans don't have the cultural knowledge on how to handle radioactive stuff that is lethal for millions of years. So, your world might need to put all the power plants in solar orbit so that an accident will wind up away from the planet.

Answer (score 2):

- idk, would like to keep it as a comment, but let it be an extended comment then, as per mod request. (*Frame challenge or answer should be posted as such. – L.Dutch♦ 1 hour ago*)

Yes.

There are certain difficulties at moderating the power of nuclear plants according to changing demand, but it is not a problem that stops from building 9x more power plants, because excess energy is easier to deal with than absence of energy.

But if you would like to be on a more efficient side of things then build some balancing consumers along with those power plants is a good thing. Wich would be using, what would be as of today, excess of energy - using it for recycling as an example.

With intermittent sources - if one does not have energy, that's the end - no energy. Excess of energy it's always an opportunity for some useful activity.

The problem is a bit bigger than that, as electricity is just a portion of the energy we use, and if I recall correctly it is 1/6 of the total, but lost the link to a wiki page. So if you want to go full nuclear it may be a bit more work than just 9x.